# Scala Arrays - pretty print a N-dimensional Matrix

Tags: arrays, scala

I want to create a method that prints an N size matrix (of a predefined type, in this case double and with N unknown and fixed array lenght) with a predefined format. **For example in a 2 * 2 * 2 matrix(cubic) of Double the result should be this**:

```
[
    [
        [
            [0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0]
        ],
        [
            [0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0]
        ],
        [
            [0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0]
        ]
    ]
]
```

at the moment I have created a method like this that does not make the needed indentation:

```
 def func(arr: Array[_]):String = {
    var output = for (a <- arr) yield {
      if ( a.isInstanceOf[Double] ) {
        a
      } else {
        func(a.asInstanceOf[Array[_]])
      }
    }
    output.mkString("[", ",", "]")
  }
```

Is the approach I am using efficient? Is it okay to use a callback function? Could you give me some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have working example with indentation:

```scala
 def func(arr: Array[_], pprintDeep:Int = 2, indentation:Int = 0):String = {
    val prefix1 = "  " * indentation
    val prefix2 = prefix1 + "  "

    val output = arr.map {
      case x: Array[_] => func(x, pprintDeep-1, indentation + 1) 
      case other if pprintDeep > 0 => prefix2 + other.toString
      case other => other.toString
    }

    if (pprintDeep > 0) output.mkString(s"$prefix1[\n", ",\n", s"\n$prefix1]")
    else prefix1 + output.mkString(s"[", ",", s"]")
}
```

Is it good? Rather not best (concatenates many strings in place). We should rather use `StringBuilder` if we care about performance, but for not heavy use case it should be fine.

Few comments about your approach:

- `a.isInstanceOf[Double]` will work for double but you could care about more types, and then such `if ... else` tree become hard to read and maintain. Use match with types as shown in my example.
- You assumed that everything that is not double is Array... risky. Use type matched as shown above.
- If you really care about performance you need to Benchmark it on your own. You can also use one of existing libraries that will print it for you (for example lihaoyi.com/PPrint, lihaoyi.com/upickle)
- working code: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YdGFHce/0
- code that works well with strings also: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YdGFHce/10

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I think it's a better approach to use match instead of if...else tree.

Comment: @LuigiAntonioMattinò I have edited answer once again. You could use `map { case ... => ...}` instead of `for(...) {...}`. This simplifies solution a bit :).

Comment: Oh... and keep in mind that it is impossible to match for example `case x:Array[Double] =>` due to type erasure! Just be aware of that. Have nice day :)